# trouble using @fontface in semantic-ui

Tags: html, css, font-face, semantic-ui

I'm trying to create a website via **semantic-ui**, and my editor is **Sublime Text 2**, and my virtual server ix **XAMPP**.
I need to use a custom font for whole body text.
i have created a main.css file (which is linked in head of course), and i have put the fontface like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Dinar One Medium_MRT";
    src:url('../fonts/Dinar One Medium_MRT.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

i have created another snippet called **`body`** and it's like:

```
body{
    font-family:'Dinar One Medium_MRT';
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

but when i run the website, my font isn't applied to texts. i have tried many things but didn't work.
i appreciate any help.
tnx for your time!

Comment: Check in the console network tab if the font is being loaded. Remove the spaces in the font name file.

Comment: i tested it, it loads the font, but still nothing happenes

Answer (score 0):

Following are the generic approaches that can help you to resolve this issue:

a. First check whether semantic-ui.css files load before your custom css file. Your custom css file must load after semantic to have higher precedence.

b. Font property is an inheritable CSS property. It means that if you have applied it on the body tag then all the html elements will inherit it from body tag provided no intermediate element have different value of font-family property specified. Make sure that no such element exists in your DOM. Also, your font-file should show up in the network tab with 200 status.

c. Calculate the specificity of the font family property of the elements. Sometimes, we do not get expected results even after downloading of the new fonts because our font-family has lower specificity(precedence).

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to override all the font in the body, you just need to use the site.overrides file alongside the site.variables file located in src/site/globals

In the site.variables, set the @fontname variable

```
@fontName : fontname;
```

In the site.overrides file, insert your @font-face css rule

```
@font-face { 
  font-family: fontname; 
  src:url('/link/to/font/fontname.ttf'); 
}
```

You of course need to have gulp-watch running in node.js and save these changes